# two filed in a wpf comboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I fill my ComboBox like this

```
            using (MorEntities1 c = new MorEntities1())
        {
            var myViewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = c.People.ToList() };
            myViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(
              new SortDescription("Family_Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            );
            CB_Coehn.ItemsSource = myViewSource.View;
            CB_Coehn.DisplayMemberPath = "Family_Name";
            CB_Coehn.SelectedValuePath = "Person_Id";
            CB_Coehn.SelectedIndex = 0;
       }
```

But in the database I have a field First Name and field Last Name , How can I view the two fields in the ComboBox (LastName , FirstName) ?

This is in WPF and c#

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Itemscontrol ItemTemplate in code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937609/how-to-create-itemscontrol-itemtemplate-in-code-behind)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're doing this in the code-behind vs. doing it in XAML? You could could easily implement @mydogisbox answer in XAML.

Comment: I totally agree with @Ryan on this one.  This feels like a WinForms way of making a dynamic UI.

Comment: Happily, can you help me how to do this in XAML?

Comment: @user1095549 I've updated my answer to include the XAML code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the "People" class, you could create a new property called "DisplayName" that formats it the way you want and set your DisplayMemberPath to that property:

```
public string DisplayName
{
    get { return string.format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName); }
}

CB_Coehn.DisplayMemberPath = "DisplayName";
```

If you can do all of this in XAML instead of the code-behind, you can do it like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CB_Coehn">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0}, {1}">
                            <Binding Path="LastName" />
                            <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Note: I have NOT tested this code, only going by memory, but it should be at least very close.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work or I do not understand, how do I connect the XAML to the entity? If possible a clearer example and again sorry and thank you

Comment: @user1095549 please update your question with what you tried in the XAML? I'll need more code to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `itemscontrol` `itemtemplate` which contains two labels and then bind their `Text` properties to the item.firstName and item.lastName.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f230804d-fc0f-4321-a61e-69a2c890b28d/) for an example.